# Play! Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:

Tags: java, playframework

I've installed play 1.2.5 framework. My application worked fine. But after reboot I can't run it. Also I can't run brand new application created with play.

I have on start up:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
Could not find the main class: .  Program will exit.
```

I have reinstalled play. But without success.

Where could be problem?

Comment: Does this mean you are trying to run it from command line? Could you please post the command line with which you are trying to run your program?

Comment: I run it via "play run" in command line

Comment: Then you surely must type "play run YourClassName" as Peter suggests :)

Comment: But how it works before? Also I tryied this sample 
http://www.playframework.com/documentation/1.2.5/guide1#aProjectcreationa

and result is the same.

Comment: `play run` is the correct way to run it. I don't know why this wouldn't work though. What OS are you trying to run on?

Answer (score 1):

This question must be very old. I solved this issue today by adding

```
jvm.memory=-Xms64M -Xmx128M 
%dev.jvm.memory=-Xms64M -Xmx128M
%prod.jvm.memory=-Xms64M -Xmx128M 
%demo.jvm.memory=-Xms64M -Xmx128M
```

these four lines in application.conf file.